# WKWebView not loading second CSS

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am loading local HTML with `WKWebView`. The HTML file is loading `main.css` file from the same location. CSS works.

If I click a link, loading another HTML file from lets say `dir/another.html` which is loading CSS with `../main.css` **the link will not even open**.

When I remove the CSS link from `dir/another.html`, the HTML will load.

Can someone help me with this? o.O

---

**ViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    content.isOpaque = false
    content.uiDelegate = self
    content.navigationDelegate = self
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: result?.id, withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "location".localized)!
    // result?.id is pointing to index.html at "location".localized

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    content.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
    content.load(request)

    super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

---

**1st HTML** `index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="anything">
        <a href="dir/another.html">Link</a>
    </div>
    ...
```

**2nd HTML** `dir/another.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="anything">
        <a href="dir/another.html">Link</a>
    </div>
    ...
```

---

**More info on demand** :)

Comment: What kind of error you have? I mean in console (F12). If any

Comment: sorry @kademat, what kind of console? Xcode output?

Comment: "More info on demand" How about more info to start with? You have not shown any code — how you are "loading local HTML", what your actual HTML looks like, nothing.

Comment: @TomášPánik I mean the console from for example Google Chrome after clicking your link: [ExampleConsole](https://snag.gy/NfPGcv.jpg) No output in console after clicking a link is also helpful information :)

Comment: sorry @kademat, I can not access any kind of console from within an iOS simulator where my app is running...

Comment: sorry @matt, editing question :)

Comment: @matt I believe the question is now complete

Comment: Thanks for adding code :) Can you try to move for a second `dir/another.html` into `another.html`, edit `../style.css` to `style.css` and confirm that it is working? The purpose of this is to eliminate other kind of errors like some configuration problems with links

Comment: `content.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)` You are limiting access to `url` but that is not where the other page is. Seems as simple as that.

Comment: @matt you are right I didn't notice that. is there a simple way to allow the whole root folder?

Comment: You can connect Safari to your Simulator WKWebView in the Develop menu (you may need to enable this menu in Safari's Preferences -> Advanced)

Comment: @DavidS. lol this is cool :D didn't know that

Comment: @DavidS. matt was right. an error occurred trying to load the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying:

```
content.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
```

So you are limiting access to *this* directory (the one signified by `url`). You are then quite rightly being blocked when you attempt to access a resource in a *different* directory.

Comment: I understood your previous comment regarding this, you are right :) matt please, is there any simple solution to use this method and allowReadAccessTo the HTML root dir including all the stuff there?

Comment: Use the URL of `Bundle.main` itself?

Comment: how to do that exactly? sorry for noobish questions